# preserving header footer while combining several doc files into one

Tags: powershell, ms-word

this code creates some files with different header and footer.
I want them to merge into one with preserving there header and footer 
how can i  do that in **powershell**

```
$val=ls $dir
set-variable -name wdAlignPageNumberCenter -value 1 
foreach ($file in $val){
    $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $true
    $Doc = $Word.Documents.Add()
    $Section = $Doc.Sections.Item(1)
    $Header = $Section.Headers.Item(1)
    $Footer = $Section.Footers.Item(1)
    $Footer.PageNumbers.Add($wdAlignPageNumberCenter)
    ****some code******
    $filedata = (get-content $filename)
    $Footer.Range.Text=$page
    $head="$abcd`t`tFile ID: $file"
    $Header.Range.Text = $head  
    $line_count = 0
    ***some code*******
    $savepath="D:\$file.docx"
    $Doc.SaveAs([ref]$savepath) 
    $Doc.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start a new section in your new Word file before adding each old Word file.  Each section of a Word document can have its own header/footer.  But, if you don't specify that the new header/footer is independent, you will change the previous header/footer.  Do it manually first to get the hang of it.

I just realized, this is basically the same thing you were told yesterday, with a similar problem.